# Ionic Build Failed: JAVA_HOME is invalid

Tags: java, ionic-framework

I wanted to start my first build with ionic. But the Build fails very soon with the following error:

```
Running command: E:\Apps\ASV\Node\node.exe E:\Apps\ASV\Code\MyASV\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js E:\Apps\ASV\Code\MyASV
add to body class: platform-android
Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_77
```

I tried several things over the past hour to fix this. I deinstalled all Java related stuff, reinstalled it, set the JAVA_HOME several times to the jdk path, added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the path-variable, but nothing fixed it. Currently my JAVA_HOME, which i had to create manually, looks like this at the moment:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
```

Please note that this path is different to the one in the error message. The 'Java' is written in lowercase and in uppercase, I don't know if this is relevant. Also changing this JAVA_HOME variable and then trying a rebuild gives the same error, the changed variable seems to have no effect on the one ionic uses.

How can I fix this? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: make sure you close and re-open any cmd prompt terminals, or applications that were running. They will not get the JAVA_HOME updates until you restart them.

Comment: Tried restarting a couple of times, unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: Yes there is a java.exe

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i fixed it. The Error

```
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

Is quite irritating. The error was that the PATH-variable missed an entry like

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
```

Somehow

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

still causes the error.

Comment: i have a same error, and the `java - version`, show me that, `C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\AppUPC>java -version
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'`

Answer (score 1):

it should be pointing to JDK\bin folder , usually C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk*\bin directory.

I recently tried in my new windows PC and gone through same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit your enviroment variables of your box to point the JAVA_HOME to the currnent jdk bin/ directory

Comment: Edit the enviroment variables of my box?

Comment: Yes, your box has environment variables. JAVA HOME is one of them. If it is a Windows box, search on the control panel for environment variables. Some poking around should find where you can edit them.