# Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cmd, java-8, javac

I am new to ionic development.
For the development i have installed the requirements that need for ionic development.I am creating ionic version 1 applications.

My problem is, i installed jdk1.8.0_212 and set path in system variables.

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212
```

and in path

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;C:\gradle-5.4-all\gradle-5.4\bin
```

Then i run the command

```
ionic cordova run android
```

I am getting this:

```
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 
installed.
You can get it from the following location:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads- 
2133151.html

Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova run android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

When i run javac i am getting this:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Please help me to solve this problem, and i am suffering from this 3 days.

Please find ionic info

```
ionic info

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.12.0 
(C:\Users\sreek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.4
@ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova- 
plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\sreek\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.4.1
OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: What happens when you try `javac -version` yourself right in the same console used for the other command?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer at : 
[Ionic Build Failed: JAVA_HOME is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608561/ionic-build-failed-java-home-is-invalid)

you need to explicitly mention the java home complete path with bin in path variable too. Also make sure to restart the console to reflect the changes.

Comment: Hi, The problem has solved!!  i enabled hyper-v and also, jdk 12 installed.Set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in user-variables and added that path in system variable.